# Why I can't read a state in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have the following code:

```
export default class Testing extends Component {
    state = ({
            data: []
    });

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
                data: this.props.values
        });
        console.log(this.state.posts); //prints empty but if I do
        console.log(this.props.values); //prints the array correctly
    }
```

Where is the error since I can print the props not the state?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not storing anything in `this.state.posts`. Your initial state only contains `data`.

Also when you construct your initial state you should do it like this:

```
state = {
  data: []
}
```

You do not need the `( )` around it.

---

If you are wanting to print a value from state as soon as you have stored it you must use the callback functionality of state. This is due to the fact that `setState` is asynchronous and takes time to set the value. Currently you are trying to read the value before it has been set, use the callback functionality like below.

```
this.setState({
  data: this.props.values
}, () => console.log(this.state.data));
```

Here are some great articles on `setState`.

- https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-is-asynchronous-52ead919a3f0
- https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296
- https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-function-56eb940f84b6

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the `( )` when you set the initial state because it is an object.

```
 export default class Testing extends Component {
        state = { //remove (
                data: []
        }; //remove )
```

Answer (score 0):

Also worth noting, setState is an async function. You will not be able to getState directly after setState.

In order to get the state right away, you would provide a callback to setState() https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate